# How to make web page load when scrolling in laravel project

Tags: laravel, scroll, infinite

I am doing a laravel project. i want to make web page content load when scrolling. i tried with several types. but not suceed.

Comment: As in continuous scrolling (e.g. facebook or twitter)? Please can you explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: yes. i tried some java script codes which i found from google.

Comment: Can you let us know what it is? I imagine there are quite a few javascript snippets that you can get from google. Please also explain what you tried and how/why it didn't work.